# Finding $E[\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i\overline{Y_n}]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am in a new class and I do not understand my instructor's proofs. I have a question about a specific part of the proof. The expression is this:
$$E\left[\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i\overline{Y_n}\right]$$
For random variables that are I.I.D. I concluded that you could treat $\overline{Y_n}$ like a constant. It is defined in the question as $\dfrac{1}{n}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i\right)$. It is also given that $E[Y_i]=\mu$.

So then I got:
$$=\overline{Y_n}E\left[\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i\right]$$
$$=\mu nE[Y_i]$$
Finally, $E\left[\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i\overline{Y_n}\right] = n\mu^2$.

My instructor got a final answer of $\sigma^2 + n\mu^2$ with the following justification:

[image]

What am I missing? Thank you so much!

Comment: Notice that $\overline{Y_n}$ is not a constant, but a random variable, so you cannot take it out of the expectation.

Comment: in $\bar{Y_n}$, there is a $Y_i$ term, so should treat the $\frac{1}{n}Y_i^2$ term as a variance in the sum.

Comment: So I see another part of his solution and it states:
$$E\left[\sum_{i=0}^n (\overline{Y}_n)^2\right] = nE[(\overline{Y}_n)^2] = n(var(\overline{Y})+E[(\overline{Y})]^2)$$ where
$ var(\overline{Y}) = \dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and $E[\overline{Y}] = \mu^2$. 

Is that equivalent to what my instructor wrote as the last expression before solving then?